# system("pause") for linux in gcc C

Tags: gcc, c

What is the system("pause") equivalent in Linux on C language. not C++.

I want to use that for my c program. Theres a logout function. But before it returns to the main login function i want to give user a message that he is successfully logged out.

my function is

```
void logout() {
    printf("You are successfully logged out\n");
    system("pause");
    login();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getchar` to achieve that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void logout() {
    printf("You are successfully logged out\n");
    int c = getchar();
    login();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. Sorry, I cant up vote because I'm new here.

Comment: @ShamanSharif If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Has the `int c =` allocation any reason to be there? (not a C coder, just curious)

Comment: @Aaron Not really, but it just makes it clear that the function returns something.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the user to be required to hit ENTER, the only option would using the following header files:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

Then the code would be:

```
struct termios oldt, newt;
char c;

// Save the current terminal attributes
tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);

// Put the terminal into raw mode
newt = oldt;
newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

// Read a single character from the terminal
c = getchar();
printf("You typed: %c\n", c);

// Restore the original terminal attributes
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
```